# Sendgrid API Keys statistics

Tags: sendgrid

Is there a way to query email delivery from a Sendgrid account which includes the API Key used to send that email? We dont have subusers but a bunch of Keys used by different applications instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the [extended email activity history add on](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/billing/addons/email_activity) you can [fetch your email activity from the API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-all-messages). One of the query types you can use to filter the results is the `api_key_id`. So, you can loop through your API key IDs and return the emails sent by each one.

Comment: Here's a link to the current [search page within SendGrid](https://app.sendgrid.com/email_activity) if you don't want to use the API link philnash gave